# Different behaviour for NullPointerException and IllegalAccessException

Tags: exception, nullpointerexception, throws, illegalaccessexception

I am trying to understand throws clause in JAVA , I wrote the following
piece of code:

```
class check
{
    static void demo()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello\n");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("demo");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        demo();
    }
}
```

I understand that it won't compile as the exception has to be handled
in the main method and demo() should be defined with specifying a throws
clause for IllegalAccessException.

But when I change the exception to NullPointerException, the same
program compiles and executes:

```
class check
{
    static void demo()
    {
    System.out.println("Hello\n");
    throw new NullPointerException("Demo");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    demo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Thanks.